# CORS problem with axios from a Vue app to a PHP API running on WAMP

Tags: php, apache, vue.js, cors, axios

I have trouble making an XHR request with axios from a Vue app to a PHP API running on WAMP.

The error message is the following :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/myapp/api/test/1' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

As you can see, it's a problem with CORS. After some documentation, here is what I have been doing to fix it (still not working).

Axios call :

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost/myapp/api/test/1',
  data: JSON.stringify({}),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
  crossdomain: true,
});
```

If I visit http://localhost/myapp/api/test/1 in my web browser, I got my response.

I attempted putting this line of code in my PHP API, in my entry point (index.php)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I configured WAMP :

Changed httpd-vhosts.conf and httpd.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- Activated the "headers_module" in apache's modules
- Rebooted everything, cleared my cache, tried from another browser ...

Still not working, am I missing something ?

Comment: You need to choose one method. Either you do it via Apache (you don't need an extra Directory directive as your document root is already that folder), or via PHP. If you use PHP you don't need headers_module. Once you have implemented one of the methods, check the actual response headers and see if you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set. Then report back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this at the top of my index.php file to fix CORS problems:

```
function cors() {
    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            // may also be using PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

        exit(0);
    }
}
cors();
```

Comment: Albert Pinto's answers solves the problem but thank you for this piece of code ! I'm going to integrate it right away.

Comment: works like a charm, 100 points!

Answer (score -1):

Try this extension for cross origin.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc

Comment: You might have posted the wrong link because I don't see what this had to do with CORS !

Comment: use this.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc